# CSS to get rid of white space in Wordpress Twenty Nineteen theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

My page at [www.risingtidescoffeecompany.com/home/](https://www.risingtidescoffeecompany.com/home/) has a white space below the navigation bar/above the large slider.

I am trying to figure out how to remove that white space, making the slider below the masthead flush with the navigation bar. I have already hidden the entry title using CSS, and I have tried several suggestions I found on Google, though nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the inspector it looks like your problem is the top margin imposed by the following css, (line 5196)

```
/* Blocks */
/* !Block styles */
.entry .entry-content > *,
.entry .entry-summary > * {
  margin: 32px 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

And it reapears in the media query, (line 5217)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .entry .entry-content > *,
  .entry .entry-summary > * {
    margin: 32px 0;
  }
}
```

It is in the theme you mentioned `themes/twentynineteen/style.css?ver=1.4`

If both css lines are deactivated the gap goes away, tested in chrome.

[image]